# Why isn't the CSS override working on nested button?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML and CSS like below (see fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/shyamh/zfwkt/)

```
<div class="tk-toolbar">
  <button class="tk-button-overrides" type="button">
        <span>one button</span>
  </button>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
    <button type="button">
        <span>another button</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button">
        <span>third button</span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.tk-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.tk-toolbar div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}
.tk-toolbar button[type=button] {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #fff2f2;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.tk-toolbar button:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.tk-toolbar button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
/* I also tried
   .tk-toolbar .tk-button-overrides
   .tk-toolbar button[type=button] .tk-button-overrides
 *  
 */
.tk-button-overrides  {
    padding-right: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The override I'm trying to apply with tk-button-no-label gets overwritten. How can I get that to actually work?

Thanks

Comment: Try with .tk-toolbar button[type=button].tk-button-overrides as the css selector for the override

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [CSS Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). The specificity for `.tk-toolbar button[type=button]` is `0,0,2,1` while the specificity for `.tk-toolbar .tk-button-no-label` is `0,0,2,0` and thus the former one overrides the later one. By adding `button[type=button]` we make it more specific i.e. `0,0,3,1`.

```
.tk-toolbar button[type=button].tk-button-no-label  {
    padding-right: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfwkt/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can either force the override with !important

```
.tk-button-overrides  {
   padding-right: 100px !important;
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

Or select more strictly like this:

```
.tk-toolbar button[type=button].tk-button-overrides  {
   padding-right: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Usage of `!important` should generally be a last resort, rather than a go-to solution.

Comment: @ajp15243 I have updated my answer to include more way to do this. Thanks.